How to code `RealNVP` using `invertibleNetworks.jl`?
I am using invertibleNetworks.jl as a library for normalizing flows. However, the examples included are for the GLOW architecture and others, but I would like to use the RealNVP architecture, and I have not been able to do so. Could someone guide me on how to create a RealNVP model using the API provided by invertibleNetworks.jl?
